# Analysing multithreaded core files on linux with gdb

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, postmortem-debugging

I am currently investigating an issue with a multithreaded program on linux. I can use gdb to look what each thread does and why the thing crashed. Nevertheless I do miss a way to simply print an overview of all threads, including data like thread state, mutex a thread is waiting for, etc.

Is there a way to get that data out of the core file? Or is that at least possible when the program runs (/proc?)?

Comment: Dunno about all state, but you can use `thread apply all ...`. E.g. `thread apply all where` will print the stack for each thread.

Comment: `thread apply all...` is what I do.

Comment: How would you do what you want in a single-threaded application?

Comment: what do you mean by thread state?  I think it's doable to get some information of any thread with a core file but the method might depend on the platform...  Say, some may have thread register from which you can get he thread struct of the thread.